# Go router navigation with page refresh on return

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

Our app has grown significantly over the last year. We’ve added a lot of features and also added push notifications and deep links which require a better approach when it comes to navigation.

We’re currently using Navigator only and we’re thinking to move to go router!

I did an MVP with go router and bottom navigation and I seem to have an issue refreshing a page.

Let’s say that we have three bottom navigation tabs [Home, Profile, Settings] and from Home I can start a different flow which the bottom navigation won’t be visible. In the end of the flow I want to press a button and get redirected to our Home which is still in the widget tree. What’s the best way to add a BLOc event based on a condition after navigating to Home?

Any thoughts would be really helpful!

Thanks

I have tried using RouteAware to determine whether Home is the route on top and execute an action without success.

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.